Setting contribution custom fields during online event registration
I have a custom field set that is tied to Contributions. Most of the custom fields have default values. On my standard Contribution pages, I include the custom fields in a profile, and then I use JavaScript to hide the fields that I don't want the user to change. (Probably I could just set the Visibility of the field to No in the profile, but I've not experimented with that. But that's not the question for this post.)
My question is this: I have a paid Event with an Online Registration form. How do I include my Contribution custom fields in the profile for the Event Registration? The only fields that I can choose from are fields for Individuals and Participants, not Contributions.
Thanks!

Good question. not sure what sort of Answers might show up. only workaround i could suggest is to see if CiviRules could be used to set those values for you.

Out of curiosity, what data (generally speaking) are you collecting with these fields?  Depending on the circumstances and the data, we've addressed this with a couple of clients by duplicating the fields for participant records, but whether that's appropriate depends on how you need to report on the data in question.
